# Verb "haben" + Partikel "zu"

Tags: word-usage, verb

Beispielsätze:

> Ich habe zu danken.
> Ich habe eine Wohnung zu vermieten.

Wird hier der Gebrauch der Partikel *zu* durch das Verb *haben* ausgelöst (wie z. B. "*Ich habe mir **vorgenommen** / ich **habe vor**, regelmäßig Sport **zu** treiben.*"), oder geht es hier um eine andere, besondere Struktur? Falls ja, wie heißen solche Konstruktionen? (Ich wusste nicht so recht, was ich nachschlagen sollte.)

Vielen Dank!

Comment: @Hubert: eine kurze Frage an dieser Stelle: Wird hier vor "oder" tatsächlich ein Komma gesetzt? Gelten die Satzteile etwa nicht als gleichrangig?

Comment: Grundsätzlich sollte hier kein Komma stehen, das ist richtig. Aber es gibt auch das fakultative Komma: Man kann ein Komma setzen, wenn zwei selbstständige Teilsätze (in deinem Fall: *»Wird der Gebrauch ausgelöst?«* und *»Geht es um eine Struktur?«*) aneinandergereiht werden und man die Struktur des Gesamtsatzes verdeutlichen will. Diese Struktur des Gesamtsatzes erschien mir hier wegen des Klammereinschubs ein wenig unklar, weswegen ich das Komma für angebracht halte. Außerdem beginnt der nächste Satz mit »Falls ja«, er bezieht ...

Comment: ... sich also nur auf eine der beiden Teilfragen. Der ganze Satz ist eine Entweder-Oder-Frage, dahinter macht »falls ja« keinen Sinn. (»Bist du zuhause oder im Büro? Falls ja, ...«) Das Komma hilft hier auch, die zweite Teilfrage stärker von der ersten zu trennen, wodurch dann beim nächsten Satz klarer wird, dass sich *»falls ja«* nur auf die zweite der beiden Teilfragen bezieht.

Comment: ... verstanden, besten Dank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die beiden Sätze aus der Frage sehen zwar ähnlich aus, folgen aber unterschiedlichen Bauplänen:

#### Ich habe zu danken

Hier bedeutet das Muster: *»jemand hat etwas zu tun«* dasselbe wie: *»jemand muss etwas tun«.* Es geht also um eine Pflicht oder um eine Erwartung, die erfüllt werden muss.

> Nein, Fabian kann nicht mit dir spielen, denn Fabian **hat** noch seine Hausübungen **zu** machen.
> Nein, Fabian kann nicht mit dir spielen, denn Fabian **muss** noch seine Hausübungen machen.

> Die verdammte Kaffeemühle **hat** Kaffee **zu** malen, wenn ich sie einschalte.
> Die verdammte Kaffeemühle **muss** Kaffee malen, wenn ich sie einschalte.

> Der Autofahrer **hat** aus**zu**weichen oder **zu** bremsen, wenn vor ihm ein Fußgänger auf die Fahrbahn tritt.
> Der Autofahrer **muss** ausweichen oder bremsen, wenn vor ihm ein Fußgänger auf die Fahrbahn tritt.

> Ich **habe zu** danken.
> Ich **muss** danken.

#### Ich habe eine Wohnung zu vermieten.

Das Muster *»jemand hat etwas zu tun«* sieht zwar gleich aus wie zuvor, es ist aber syntaktisch anders zu interpretieren, nämlich so: *»jemand besitzt etwas, mit dem etwas zu tun ist«* oder *»... mit dem etwas getan werden kann«.*

> Herr Huber hat Hühner zu verkaufen.
> Herr Huber besitzt Hühner. Diese Hühner sollen verkauft werden.

> Wir haben einen Ruf zu verlieren.
> Wir haben einen (guten) Ruf. Diesen guten Ruf könnten wir verlieren.

> Ich habe eine Wohnung zu vermieten.
> Ich besitze eine Wohnung. Diese Wohnung soll vermietet werden.

---

Besondere Namen für diese Konstruktionsmuster sind mir nicht bekannt.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Antwort, Hubert! Ich hatte irgendwie das Gefühl, dass hier eine modale Bedeutung dahintersteckt, war mir jedoch nicht ganz sicher...

Comment: Nur als Anmerkung: die 2. Bedeutung kann auch immer als die 1. interpretiert werden: "Herr Huber hat Hühner zu verkaufen" => "Herr Huber muss Hühner verkaufen". Wird meist verwendet, um klarzustellen, dass keine andere Tätigkeit möglich ist (er kann deswegen jetzt nichts anderes tun), oder um eine Ziel zu beschreiben (er muss einen Weg finden, die Hühner zu verkaufen)

Answer (score 1):

## Fall 1: *haben* + *zu*-Infinitiv

Das Verb *haben* in Verbindung mit einem *zu*-Infinitiv wird in der aktuellen Auflage der Duden-Grammatik als **Modalitätsverb** bezeichnet (Randnummer 827). Die Konstruktion ist als **modaler Infinitiv** bekannt (siehe z.B. [hier](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1524/9783050062341.8/pdf)). Sie kann in aller Regel durch *müssen* umschrieben werden.

> Die Gerichte werden einige Fragen *zu klären haben*.
> = Die Gerichte werden einige Fragen *klären müssen*.

## Fall 2: Akkusativ + *zu*-Infinitiv

Der zweite Fall hat keinen Namen, der mir bekannt wäre; die IDS-Grammatik spricht lakonisch von einer "Peripheriegruppe" (S. 1280; zitiert [hier](https://jyx.jyu.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/37868/GERUNDIV%20final%20draft.pdf)). Die Beispiele sind hier auch variabler und zeigen Merkmale von Idiomatisierung (sind also nicht nach allgemeinen Regeln aufgebaut). Neben *haben* sind auch andere Verben möglich und der Infinitiv wird gelegentlich nominalisiert.

> Wann gibts was *zum Essen*?
> "Wann gibt es etwas, was man essen kann?"
>
> *(aber beim modalen Infinitiv nur:)* Du hast *zu essen*, was auf den Tisch kommt.
> "Du musst essen, was auf den Tisch kommt."

Wie die Paraphrasen zeigen, unterscheiden sich die beiden Fälle auch in ihrer Bedeutung.